# Localized date ranges

Tags: biblatex, languages, date, iso

`biblatex` (with `biber`) supports all kinds of date information, including ranges. Dates follow ISO 8601, which is great, and they are localized (plays nice with `babel`).

I would like to get localized date ranges in-text, not associated with `bib` entries. Basically, the `biblatex` way of handling dates but not while using bibliographies. I want to do something like `\datecommand{2012-10-01/2012-10-12)` and get

> Oct. 1–12, 2012

Then switch to `portuges` and get

> 1–12 de out. de 2012

And so on for several more languages. I've tried two options, to no avail:

- `datetime2`: localized, but no date ranges (I've seen code for how to create a date range, but I gather one would need to rewrite it for each language)
- `isodate`: date ranges, but not localized beyond several English varieties and a few (but not many) languages; it doesn't cover all the languages I need.

Is there any obvious way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well you could use biblatex + biber:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{autogenerated-dates.bib}
\newwrite\mydates
\newcounter{datecnt}
\NewDocumentCommand\datecommand {m}
{%
  \stepcounter{datecnt}%
  \immediate\write\mydates{@misc{date\thedatecnt,date={#1}}}%
  \citedate{date\thedatecnt}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\mydates=autogenerated-dates.bib}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\mydates}
\begin{document}
\datecommand{2012-10-01/2012-10-12}

\datecommand{2018/2020}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves my problem.So it seems that a solution is to actually use `biblatex`. It actually crossed my mind before to have ad hoc entries for each date I wanted, but that would soon get cumbersome, and I had no idea how to generate the entries on the fly.

Comment: +1 this is neat

Answer (score 3):

The strategy here has several components to develop `\datecommand`, as requested by the OP.  First, I had to examine which of three different branches to use:

1. sharing a common month and year (`\dayrange`)
2. sharing a common year (`\monthrange`)
3. spanning beyond a year's boundary (`\yearrange`}

Then, for branches 1 and 2, I had to develop special routines to override the checks and behavior employed by `datetime2`.  In the end, I found that a routine `\DTMifbool`, with four arguments, was used to typeset the various pieces.  Therefore, I had to selectively replace this macro with an alternative, when needed.

In case 1, I had to compare argument `#2` to the string `showdayofmonth`.  If I found a match, I replaced `\DTMifbool` with `\altADTMifbool`, which did no checks on day's format, so that I could replace the day with a range like `1--12`.  The replacement also prevented the day's suffix like `st`, `nd` and `rd` from being printed.

In case 2, I had to compare argument `#2` to the string `showyear`.  If I found a match, I replaced `DTMifbool` with `\altBDTMifbool`, which basically shut down the call altogether, so that no separator nor year were printed (example `de 2012`).  I then restored `\DTMifbool` and finished up with `-- <closing date>`/

In case 3, I simply typeset `<opening date> -- <closing date>`.

In the MWE, I show the three branches, each for `british`, `french`, and `portuges` language styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,british,portuges]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,calc]{datetime2}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORKS FOR LUA + XELATEX + PDFLATEX ENGINES
%\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
%\makeatletter
%\let\strcmp\pdf@strcmp
%\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%% WORKS ONLY FOR PDFLATEX AND XELATEX ENGINES
\let\strcmp\pdfstrcmp
%%%%%%%%%%%%% END
\DTMusemodule{british}{en-GB}
\DTMusemodule{french}{french}
\DTMusemodule{portuges}{portuges}

\newcommand\datecommand[1]{\dcaux(#1)}
\def\dcaux(#1-#2-#3/#4-#5-#6){%
  \ifnum\strcmp{#1}{#4}=0\relax
    \ifnum\strcmp{#2}{#5}=0\relax
      \dayrange{#1}{#2}{#3}{#6}%
    \else
      \monthrange{#1}{#2}{#3}{#5}{#6}%
    \fi
  \else
    \yearrange{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
  \fi
}

\let\svDTMifbool\DTMifbool

\newcommand\altADTMifbool[4]{%
  \ifnum\strcmp{#2}{showdayofmonth}=0\relax
    \expandafter\noparsedayofmonth
  \else
    \svDTMifbool{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\altBDTMifbool[4]{%
  \ifnum\strcmp{#2}{showyear}=0\relax
  \else
    \svDTMifbool{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\dayrange[4]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\DTMifbool\altADTMifbool
  \def\noparsedayofmonth{\number#3--\number#4\ }%
  \DTMdate{#1-#2-1}
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\monthrange[5]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\DTMifbool\altBDTMifbool
  \DTMdate{#1-#2-#3}
  \endgroup
  -- \DTMdate{#1-#4-#5}%
}
\newcommand\yearrange[6]{%
  \DTMdate{#1-#2-#3} -- \DTMdate{#4-#5-#6}%
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\branchtests{%
\par\datecommand{2012-10-01/2012-10-12}
\par\datecommand{2012-10-01/2012-11-3}
\par\datecommand{2012-10-01/2013-1-4}\par}

\selectlanguage{british}\branchtests
\hrulefill\selectlanguage{french}\branchtests
\hrulefill\selectlanguage{portuges}\branchtests
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite a nice solution for dates and date ranges with a specified year, month, and day, but it does not work in any other case (say, `2009`, `2010-10`, and `2010-10/2011-09` would not work). I should perhaps have been clearer in my question, because this does of course work for the examples I gave, but it's not the `biblatex`, ISO 8601 compliant way of handling dates, and will not handle other examples I will use but didn't provide.

Comment: @PedroTiagoMartins It was a fun problem to look at, nonetheless.

Comment: For sure! Both your answer and the one I accepted are above my ability and I learned a lot just going through how you tackled it.